# How to use variable in 2nd thread of jmeter

Tags: multithreading, properties, jmeter, global-variables

I have created a script which involves below scenario:

> 1. Thread1 Setup -login into application
> 2. Thread2 - hitting a dashboard page

I have created a variable for authorization token in setup thread1 using regular expression extractor. Now i want to use this variable in my next thread2. Please help me how to make this variable as a property , and how can i use it in the next thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
Thread Group-1 Setup
+Http Request
    - Regular Expression Extractor
    - JSR223 PostProcessor - ${__setProperty(variableForThread2,${variableFromRegEx})}

Thread Group-2 - Dashboard
+Http Request - Use the above variable as ${__property(variableForThread2)}
```

Comment: Hi , I am getting error as groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException in logs, can you please help how to resolve this .

Comment: Can you try with BeanShell PostProcessor. Ideally it should have worked with JSR223. Also share me brief details of the log

Comment: In your JSR223 Postprocessor you can also use "def variableForThread2= prev.getResponseDataAsString();"

Comment: It is working with JSR223. but in the log file i see the above error. For BeanShell post processor should i user same set property syntax?

Comment: Yes. On my side i am able to work with both property syntax and with getResponseDataAsString().

Comment: Hi I have used "def = prev.getResponseDataAsString();" as per your suggestion , Its working as expected now. Thank you for your help. Will you also explain the purpose of "def = prev.getResponseDataAsString();" or any link where i can find details about this and learn ?

Comment: This is to just **define a variable** name(variableForThread2) as per the response from previous executed step like **prev.getResponseDataAsString**. You can refer to this [link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be splitting such [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) across different Thread Groups, apart from the token there are a lot of things you will need to share.

[Well-behaved JMeter test must represent real user using real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) therefore you will need to pass not only the token, but also:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

JMeter provides appropriate Configuration Elements like [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), however they will work only within one Thread Group.

If your interest is "academic" be aware that it is possible to pass values between Thread Groups, there are at least 2 ways:

1. Use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st Thread Group to set the value and [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd Thread Group to read the value. (Remember that properties are global so if you have > 1 virtual user you will need to add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function as well)
2. Go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)